# Is there Find Replace mechanism in google-apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script, ide, google-workspace, monaco-editor

I have a lot of refactoring to do within Google Apps Script and a mechanism to Find text and Replace all would greatly simplify.  Ctrl-f gives find but not an option to replace.

Comment: Try going to [google apps script reference page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference) and type find and replace in the search box

Comment: BTW there is  find and replace in documents, spreadsheets and script editor and I believe all of them support regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

To rename a symbol, which is much more common in programming, place the cursor on that symbol you want to rename and press <kbd>F2</kbd>.

To replace, while in the find menu(<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>), and after searching for a value, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>: Replace menu will show up. This is not the recommended way to rename variables as it is very easy to rename strings or other code not intended to be renamed.

You can also see the full list of commands using <kbd>F1</kbd>. Since Google apps script IDE is based on [monaco-editor](/questions/tagged/monaco-editor)(which in turn is based on VScode), some information in the official [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved) will also help.